# Getting stuck implementing pagination in Android

Tags: android

I have the following requirements.

1. I am displaying 10 items in a ListView in which each List item displays 2 text views & one thumbnail image . I have coded to display the images asynchronously , since I need to fetch the images using url. The data for the list item is being fetched from server. In the response , I get the information whether any more pages are available for display.
2. After the user scrolls to the 10 items , I need to call the webservice to fetch the next 10 list of items from the server . When the user scrolls to the 10 th element of the first page , a small progress dialog is displayed at the end of the screen & information is fetched from the server & the view is updated . Also if the user scrolls up , new call to the webservice is not made to the server & the display contains all the list items.

I received few suggestions but am unable to implement the pagination .
Kindly help as I am stuck on this problem for more than 3 weeks.

Answer (score 0):

You might try my [`EndlessAdapter`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless) and see if either it can solve your problem directly or give you ideas of how to implement your own take on the concept.